# creating two lines in a chart in r studio

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe called `df_1`

| Publisher | Total.North.America.Sales. | Total.Europe.Sales. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ADX | 816.87 | 418.74 |
| 3RD | 595.07 | 371.27 |
| BDTT | 429.7 | 215.53 |
| RRD-Y | 265.22 | 187.72 |
| RRD-X | 253.43 | 163.32 |

I want to creat a chart like this one https://i.ibb.co/z6Qz8rV/graphic.png

I tried this code first:

```
png(file = "line_chart_2_lines.jpg")
chart1 <- plot(df_1, type = "o", col = "red", xlab = "Publisher", ylab = "Total Sales",
     main = "Sales")
lines(comp_na$`Total North America Sales`, type = "o", col = "blue")
legend(1, 110, legend = c("Europe", "N. America"),
       + col = c("red", "blue", "green"), lty = 1:1, cex = 0.9)
dev.off()
```

It did not work, I cannot identidy the syntax issue. So I tried doing it with `gglopt2`

```
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("hrbrthemes")
library(hrbrthemes)

ggplot(df_1, aes(x=df_1$comp_na.Publisher, y=df_1$comp_eu..Total.Europe.Sales.)) +
  geom_line( color="#69b3a2", size=2, alpha=0.9, linetype=2) +
  lines(comp_na$`Total North America Sales`, type = "o", col = "blue")
  theme_ipsum() +
  ggtitle("Total Sales")
```

but the outcome is a balnk chart. I'm not sure what is wrong. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to add `group = 1` into the ggplot or geom_line aes().

> For line graphs, the data points must be grouped so that it knows which points to connect. In this case, it is simple -- all points should be connected, so group=1. When more variables are used and multiple lines are drawn, the grouping for lines is usually done by variable.

Reference: [Cookbook for R, Chapter: Graphs Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2), Line graphs.](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/)

Try this:

```r
# Read data
df_1 <- read.table(text = 
"Publisher  Total.North.America.Sales.  Total.Europe.Sales.
ADX 816.87  418.74
3RD 595.07  371.27
BDTT    429.7   215.53
RRD-Y   265.22  187.72
RRD-X   253.43  163.32", 
sep = '\t', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

# Plot data
df_1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(Publisher, c(1:5)), group = 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Total.North.America.Sales.), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Total.Europe.Sales.), color = "red") +
  labs (
    title = "Total Sales",
    y     = "",
    x     = ""
  )
```

---

If you want to have a proper legend you need to convert the data into the long format (using `pivot_longer()`) to bring all the sales into one column and then use group and colour mappings in the aesthetic.

```r
df_1 %>%
  
  # Convert to tibble
  as_tibble() %>%
  
  # Make data long
  pivot_longer(cols      = c(Total.North.America.Sales., 
                             Total.Europe.Sales.),
               names_to  = "location", 
               values_to = "value") %>% 
  
  # Order the Publishers according the value
  mutate(Publisher = Publisher %>% as_factor() %>% fct_reorder(-value)) %>%
  
  # Change order of the location (for the legend)
  mutate(location = location %>% as_factor() %>% fct_relevel("Total.North.America.Sales.",
                                                             "Total.Europe.Sales.")) %>%
  
  # Plot
  ggplot(aes(x     = Publisher, 
             color = location)) +
  geom_line(aes(y     = value, 
                group = location),
                size  = 2) +
  
  # Color
  scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue", "orange")) +
  # Grid Lines
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 900, 100)) +
  # Y-Axis Limits
  expand_limits(y = c(0,900)) +
  
  # Labels
  labs(
    color = "",
    title = "North America x Europe",
    y     = "",
    x     = ""
  ) +
  
  # Formatting
  theme(legend.position    = "bottom",
        panel.background   = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey"),
        axis.ticks         = element_blank(),
        legend.key         = element_blank(),
        legend.text        = element_text(size = 10, color = "grey40"),
        plot.title         = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5, color = "grey40"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jwarz . Would you know how to insert legend for the chart into your code? I tried to adapt it adding [[[ legend("topleft",legend=colnames(df_1),lty=c(1,2),col=c("blue","red"),bg="white",lwd=2) + ]]] before labs, but R studio did not take it